# standalone gorm - grails 2.4 - messages.properties not getting loaded

Tags: grails, grails-orm

We are evaluating GORM as a replacement out hibernate code in backend, 
my messages.properties file is not getting loaded...... what am i doing wrong?

Here is my script and output :

```
$cat GORM_TEST.groovy**

import grails.orm.bootstrap.*
import grails.persistence.*
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
import org.h2.Driver

init = new HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer(Person)
def dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(Driver.name,     
"jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE", 'sa', '')
init.configureForDataSource(dataSource)


Person p1 = new Person();
p1.name = "Vinay"
p1.save();
Person p2 = new Person();
p2.name = ""
if (! p2.validate() ) {
p2.errors.allErrors.each {
    println it.dump()
}
}
p2.save();
println "Total people = " + Person.list()`

$cat messages.properties
person.name.blank=BLANK VALUE PROVIDED?????
person.name.blank.name=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I added following dependencies to CLASSPATH dependencies to CLASSPATH

```
org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:3.1.0.RELEASE  
org.grails:grails-spring:2.4.0

$groovy GORM_TEST2.groovy

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Hibernate: insert into person (id, version, name) values (null, ?, ?)
<org.springframework.validation.FieldError@71be79f5 field=name rejectedValue=
bindingFailure=false objectName=Person codes=[Person.name.blank.error.Person.name, 
Person.name.blank.error.name, Person.name.blank.error.java.lang.String, 
Person.name.blank.error, person.name.blank.error.Person.name,    
person.name.blank.error.name, person.name.blank.error.java.lang.String,   
person.name.blank.error, Person.name.blank.Person.name, Person.name.blank.name, 
Person.name.blank.java.lang.String, Person.name.blank, person.name.blank.Person.name,    
person.name.blank.name, person.name.blank.java.lang.String, person.name.blank, 
blank.Person.name, blank.name, blank.java.lang.String, blank] arguments=[name, class 
Person] defaultMessage=Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be blank>
Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_0_0_, this_.version as version2_0_0_, this_.name as 
name3_0_0_ from person this_

Total people = [Person(Vinay), Person(Vinay), Person(Vinay), Person(Vinay), 
Person(Vinay), Person(Vinay), Person(Vinay), Person(Vinay), Person(Vinay), 
Person(Vinay)]
```

I tried putting messages.properties in ./grails-app/i18n/ as well as ./i18n but no help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GORM uses Spring's `MessageSource` concept for loading messages. When used standalone no `MessageSource` is configured. It is up to you to provide one. You can do this by overriding the `getBeanDefinitions` method:

```
 init = new HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer(Person) {
    Closure getBeanDefinitions(BeanDefinitionRegistry beanDefinitionRegistry) {
         def parentDefinitions = super.getBeanDefinitions(beanDefinitionRegistry)
         return {
               parentDefinitions.delegate = delegate
               parentDefinitions.call()
               messageSource(ResourceBundleMessageSource) {
                   basenames = ['file:messages']
               }
         }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Graeme. I tried that but still messages are not being picked up. I already put messages.properties file on classpath. Here is my complete code : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b4bf00a73c31de00dc7f

Comment: Thanks Graeme, I just had to change ResourceBundleMessageSource to ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource and it worked. Thanks again!!! :-)